# Changing the initial screen

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I changed the initial screen which is not on the `Main` storyboard, I did exactly like it was written on google:

1. Changed from view controllers attribute inspector `is initial view controller`
2. deleted the “Main storyboard file base name” line and the “Storyboard Name” line in `info` file
3. added code below in scene delegate:

```swift
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let vc = LoginViewController()  // view controller which must be the new one
        window?.rootViewController = vc
```

I did all above but after running the xCode project I see only a black screen and an error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` this error is in `LoginViewController`'s textfield, I tried reAttaching `IBOutlet` but it doesn't seem to work

any solutions ?

p.s. I don't know if it will be helpful to know, but `LoginViewController` is fully copied with its own storyobard from another xCode project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
LoginViewController()
```

This view controller has outlets, meaning that it is designed in the storyboard. What you want to do here is not to create a fresh LoginViewController, as you are doing, but to extract the desired LoginViewController instance from the storyboard.

Comment: See my http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake-2/

Comment: your blog was absolutely helpful. thank you.

Comment: your answer truly helped me, but I still got the same problem, the problem is that after clicking a button my view goes to another viewcontroller but in that view controller the buttons doesn't work, I rereaded your blog, did like you said but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If the button does _something_, and you don't crash any more, my work here is done. If you have a new question about a different matter, click the Ask Question button and ask it. :)